# JSONParser gives out everything twice

Tags: c, json, jsonparser

i was trying to make a JSONParser in C and it partly works.
The only problem is that the Terminal shows everything twice.
For Example, instead of showing just "Name", it gives out "Name" Name.
Thats the Code (some of the variables and comments are in German):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct person {
    int PID; 
    int alter;
    int freunde[20];
    char* vname;
    char* nname;
}person; 
 
int MAX_PERSONS = 10; 

char* substr(const char *source, int m, int n)                     
{
    int len = abs(n - m);                            
 
    char *destination = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
 
    for (int i = m; i < n && (*(source + i) != '\0'); i++)
    {
        *destination = *(source + i);
        destination++;
    }
    *destination = '\0';
    return destination - len;
}

const char* readNext(FILE* fp)
{
    const char* string = malloc(1024);          /*Speicherreservierung*/
    const char* retvalue;

    if (fscanf(fp, "%s", string) == 1)          /*solange es erfolgreich ist, fragt es ab, bis ein leerzeichen kommt*/
    {
        while(strcmp(string,":") == 0 )         /*doppelpunkt wird ignoriert*/
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", string);                   
        }
printf("\n %s", string);                         /*gibt einen String aus*/
        if(strncmp(string,"\"",1) == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(substr(string, strlen(string)-1, 1 ),",") == 0)       /*kontrolliert, ob ein Beistrich vorkommt*/
            {
                retvalue = substr(string, 1, strlen(string)-2);  /*kommt ein Beistrich vor, so werden zwei vom ende abgezogen, sonst nur einer*/
            }
            else
            {
                retvalue = substr(string, 1, strlen(string)-1);
            }                                                   /*nun sind die Anfuehrungszeichen weg*/
printf("\n %s", retvalue);
            return    retvalue;                                   
        }
        else
        {
printf("\n %s", string);            
            return string;
        } 
    } 

    return NULL;
}

int readInit(FILE* fp)                         /*hiermit wird der Anfang der Datei gelesen*/
{
    const char* readValue= readNext(fp);
}

return strcmp(readValue,"{");                /*string wird mit { verglichen*/
                       
void readPid(FILE* fp, person* pp)
{
    const char* a = readNext(fp);               /*file pointer auf die naechste stelle*/

    if(strstr(a,  "pid")> 0)                    /*kontrolle, ob wir schon an der Stelle PID sind*/
    {
       a =  readNext(fp);                       
    }
    (*pp).PID = atoi(a);                        /*https://www.proggen.org/doku.php?id=c:lib:stdlib:atoi: die Funktion atoi wird in diesem Fall die anfuehrungszeichen los und speichert die ID ab*/
}

void readName(FILE* fp, person* pp)
{
    readNext(fp);                                 /*pointer wird weitergesetzt*/
    if(readInit(fp) != 0)                         /*ueberpruefung ob es richtig startet*/
    {
        printf("\n Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {")  ;
    }

    const char* a = readNext(fp);                     /*filepopinter geht weiter*/

    if(strstr(a,  "vname") > 0)                       /*Richtigkeits ueberpruefung*/
    {
        (*pp).vname = readNext(fp);                   /*pointer geht weiter auf namen und speichert es ins struct*/
    }

    a = readNext(fp);                                   
    if(strstr(a,  "nname") > 0)                       /*ueberpruefung ob es der nachname ist*/
    {
        (*pp).nname = readNext(fp);                   /*file pointer geht auf nachnamen und speichert*/
    }

}
int readAge(FILE* fp,person* pp )
{
   readNext;                                           /*ueberspringen des },*/

    const char* a = readNext(fp);  

    if(strstr(a,  "alter")> 0)                         /*ueberpruefung ob wir an der stelle alter sind*/
    {
       a =  readNext(fp);                              /*filepointer geht weiter zum alter*/
    }
    (*pp).PID = atoi(a); 
  return 0;  
}
int readFreunde(FILE* fp,person* pp )
{
   readNext;                                                    /*ueberspringen des ,*/

    const char* a = readNext(fp);  

    if(strstr(a,  "freunde")> 0)                        /*ueberpruefung ob wir an der stelle freunde sind*/
    {
       a =  readNext(fp);                               /*filepointer geht weiter zu den freunden ids*/
    }
    (*pp).PID = atoi(a); 
    return 0;}
/*
int * readFriends(FILE* fp)
{
    int retvalue[] = {0,1};
    
   return retvalue; 
}
*/
person* readPerson(FILE* myFileRef)                                 /*file pointer wird as parameter mitgegeben*/
{
    person* myPers = (person*) malloc(1 * sizeof(person));          /*speicher wird reserviert fuer die auszulesenden daten der person*/

    if(readInit(myFileRef) != 0)                                    /*es wird ueberprueft ob das file richtig beginnt*/
    {
        printf("\n Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {")  ;
    }

    readPid(myFileRef, myPers);                                     /*auslagerung der einzelnen daten in funktionen*/
    readName(myFileRef, myPers);
    readAge(myFileRef, myPers);
    readFreunde(myFileRef, myPers);
    
return myPers;
}
void optionone()
{
    FILE* myJson = NULL;                            /*Initialisierung des File Pointers*/

    printf("Option 1 gewaehlt \n");
    myJson = fopen("personen.json", "r");           /*file wird mit "r" geoeffnet, das heißt die Datei wird nur gelesen und nicht geaendert*/

    person* myPersLib[MAX_PERSONS] ;                        /*struct wird initialisiert*/
    int i = 0;

    if(myJson != NULL)                                      /*ueberpruefung ob das file leer ist*/
    {
        person* myPers = readPerson(myJson);                    /*ablesefunktion ausgelagert*/
        
        while(&myPers != NULL && i < MAX_PERSONS)                   /*schleife um alle strings durchzugehen, insofern das file nicht leer ist und man die maximale anzahl nicht ueberschreitet*/
        {
            myPersLib[i] = myPers;
            i++;
            myPers = readPerson(myJson);
        }

        fclose(myJson);                                         /*datei wird geschlossen*/
    } 
    else
    {
        printf("Datei nicht vorhanden");                        /*ist die Datei nicht in dem gleichen Ordner, so entsteht eine Fehlermeldung "Datei nicht vorhanden" */
    }
}
void optiontwo()
{
    char str[15];                                   
    int b = 0;
    person mypers;
    printf("\n Option 2 gewaehlt\n");

        printf("\nID eingeben: ");                          /*Abfrage der ID*/
        scanf("%d", &b);
        b = mypers.PID;

        printf("\nVorname eingeben:");                      /*Abfrage des Vornamens*/
        scanf("%s", str);
        *str = mypers.vname;                                /*string pointer weil es eine "modifiable value" sein muss*/
    
        printf("\n Nachname eingeben:");                     /*Abfrage des Nachnamens*/
        scanf("%s", str);
        *str = mypers.nname;
      
        printf("\n Alter eingeben: ");                       /*Abfrage des Alters*/
        scanf("%d", &b);
        b = mypers.alter;

      
        printf("\n ID eingeben: ");                          /*Abfrage der ID (friends)*/
        scanf("%d", &b);
        b = mypers.freunde;

}
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    printf("1. Einlesen \t 2. Eingeben und als File speichern");
    printf("\n Option waehlen: ");                                       /*mit der switch case wird die Option abgefragt, einlesen oder eingeben*/
    scanf("%d", &a);

    switch (a)                                                          
    {
        case 1:                                                         /*erste option der switch case*/
        optionone();
        
        break;
        case 2:                                                         /*zweite option der switch case*/
        optiontwo();

        break;
        default:
        printf("Ungueltige Option");                                    /*wird etwas anderes als 1 oder zwei bei der Optionsauswahl ausgewaehlt, so wird es unterbrochen und es entsteht eine Fehlermeldung*/
        break;
    }                                                               
    return 0;
}
```

And after the terminal compiles the File, thats what it spits out:

```
1. Einlesen      2. Eingeben und als File speichern
Option waehlen: 1
Option 1 gewaehlt

{
{
"pid"
pid
"1138",
1138"
"name"
name
{
{
"vname"
vname
"Leia",
Leia"
"nname"
nname
"Organa"
Organa
},
},
"alter"
alter
"21",
21"
Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {
"freunde"
freunde
[
[
{"pid"
{"pid"
Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {
"0987"}
0987"
,
,
{"pid"
{"pid"
"7778"}
7778"
]
]
Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {
},
},
{
{
"pid"
pid
Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {
"7778",
7778"
"name"
name
{
{
"vname"
vname
"Luke",
Luke"
Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {
"nname"
nname
"Skywalker"
Skywalker
},
},
Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {
"alter"
alter
"21",
21"
"freunde"
freunde
[
[
{"pid"
{"pid"
Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {
"0987"}
0987"
,
,
{"pid"
{"pid"
Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {
"1138"}
1138"
]
]
},
},
{
{
"pid"
pid
Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {
"0987",
0987"
"name"
name
{
{
"vname"
vname
"Din",
Din"
"nname"
nname
"Djarin"
Djarin
},
},
"alter"
alter
"35",
35"
Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {
"freunde"
freunde
[
[
{"pid"
{"pid"
Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {
"7778"}
7778"
,
,
{"pid"
{"pid"
"1138"}
1138"
]
]
Falsche Syntax - File does not start with {
}
}
```

Comment: Line 39: `fscanf(fp, "%s", string);` you can not write to a string declared as `const char *`, remove the `const` keyword and protect your `fscanf` from buffer overflows: `fscanf(fp, "%1023s", string)`. Or better yet, use `fgets` (or `getline` if available).

Comment: Your code has tons of warnings, some of them are critical: https://pastebin.com/3D9bf6VW , enable warnings on your compiler.

Comment: There are several `printf` statements in `readNext` that look like they could print duplicate data. It might be helpful tp preface the output with something to help you identify where it came from. Like "\n 1: %s"`